# cause numbers to appear one after another when typing in textbox but also make them add up when 0 appears

Tags: c#, textbox, numbers

**Assignment**

1. Create a Windows application accepting integer numbers as input, one at a time, in a single field.
2. A button Process causes displaying that number right below the input field, but only if it is larger than the currently displayed number (or it’s the first number processed). As soon as zero(0) has been processed, stop accepting more input.
3. Third part of the assignment: Display (above the input field) the sum of all the processed numbers.

So this is my assignment.

So far I the first part of the assignment done and the third assignment. I have no idea how to start the second part. All I have so far is

```
 label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
 label2.Text = textBox1.Text;
 label3.Text =(Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(label2.Text)).ToString();
```

If I don't make sense let me try to explain

- My first question is how do I make this more specific.. I want to be
  able to type a number into my text box and have it be sent to my
  label1 then.. when I type the next number it goes to label 2 and not
  label1.. and repeat to label3-9..
- Second question: how can I restrict the numbers so that label 1 (if
  it is a bigger number) causes label 2 to not appear.
- Final question how can I make it to where once 0 is typed into the
  textbox and appears as a label it causes the sum of all the numbers
  to appear in another label...

So sorry if this is too overwhelming if it is I can split these questions up...

here is how my assignment looks like atm

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.MaxLength = 1;
    Char digit = e.KeyChar;
    if (!Char.IsDigit(digit) && digit != 8)
        e.Handled = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
    {
        int c = Text[i];
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
        {
            Text = Text.Remove(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

private void processBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int current = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int num = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    if (num > 0)
    {
        sum += num;
        if (num > current)
        {
            label1.Text = num.ToString();
            current = num;
        }
    }
}
```

this is what i have..but the program doesn't work like how i want it to.. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using winforms? (I'm not familiar enough with WPF to tell if label is not in WPF)

Comment: It seems like you are not interpreting the assignment correctly. Your application should have a total of 4 controls: 1. Input textbox, 2. Process button, 3. text label to display largest number that was entered, and 4. text label to display running sum of all processed numbers.

Comment: Please don't use the homework tag.  It is [obsolete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) and in the process of removal.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what does that mean, exactly? What happens when you run the code, and how does that differ from what you expect? I notice that you are using the property `Text` when you try to handle the text in the textbox, but that would be a property of the form, not the textbox.

Answer (score 3):

Storing the entered numbers in labels wouldn't work well. Either you would be limited by the number of labels that you have in the form, or you would need to create labels dynamically. You could store the numbers in an array or a list, but you actually doesn't have to store the numbers at all, you can keep the sum of the numbers and forget each number once you have processed it.

Store the currently displayed number in a variable. If your program doesn't need to handle negative numbers, you can let it start out as zero:

```
int current = 0;
```

You would also need a variable to sum up all the numbers:

```
int sum = 0;
```

In the event handler for the button, parse the text from the textbox, check for zero, add it to the sum, and compare it to the currently displayed number. If it is larger, put it in the label, and in the variable:

```
int num = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
if (num > 0)
{
    sum += num;
    if (num > current)
    {
        label1.Text = num.ToString();
        current = num;
    }
}
else
{
    label2.Text = sum.ToString();
    // stop accepting input, perhaps exit?
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit new to c# this all seems quite confusing.

Comment: What is it that's confusing, and in what way?

Comment: since i did this for some reason my text box is accepting all numbers, but i want it to only accept single digits eX: 0-9

Comment: @PechengChang: A textbox accepts anything by default. You may be able to limit the length or setting a filter, alternatively verify the data before you parse it, but that's more than enough for a question on its own.